# How to check whether a textbox is present in a webpage or not using watin

Tags: c#, watin

I'm using watin and nunit in my project and I would like to know is there any way to find whether a textbox is present in a webpage or not I tried the following code but its not working

```
if (browser.TextField(Find.ById("textbox1")) != null)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
```

So how can i check whether a textbox is present or not in a webpage using watin???

Comment: In the future, please define what you mean by "its not working".  EG: throws an error, nothing happens, machine blue screens, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isThere = browser.TextField(Find.ById("textbox1")).Exists;
```